# var text - line break or any formatting not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i got a nother problem with the var text this time its the following if i have code like:

```
<script>

    var texte = {
        'title': {
            'de':'meine kleinen Tieren',
            'en':'my small animals'},

        'subtitle': {
            'de':'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text',

            'en':''},

        'email': {
            'target':'placeholder',
            'de':'Schreib mit sobald es weitere Infos gibt:',
            'en':'Email me when it is ready'},

        'submit': {
            'target':'value',
            'de': 'abschicken',
            'en': 'send'
        },

        'share_txt': {
            'de': 'bitte teilen',
            'en': 'share...'
        }


    };
```

Then everthing works. However if change one small detail the complete text doesn´t work anymore. So for example the "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text " part is to long i want to have a 
 after industry or something like this, but this doesn't work? I hope you guys understand my problem and can help me?

Comment: Javascript and Java are quite different. Please remove the Java tag.

Comment: You forgot to escape `'` in your string. Substitute `'` with `\'`

Comment: sorry i was unclear, what i want is to somehow format the long text in the string. As it is now its just one long sentence, i need a line break in it - but <br> doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use `\'`

```
'subtitle': {
            'de':'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text',

            'en':''}
```

`industry's` should be `industry\'s` Use [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)

> Each character in a string literal can be represented by an escape sequence. An escape sequence starts with a backslash ('\') that informs the JavaScript interpreter that the next character is a special character.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem i simply need to add \n to get a line break without destorying the text.